# FactoryGirl on Heroku : Trait not registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

Have *factory_girl_rails* gem installed, runs fine on local environment, but not on *Heroku*. It says:

```
Factory not registered :user.
```

Any ideas or relevant files I should post for help?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'


gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# server and database stacks
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'thin'

# template and assets stacks
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'gon'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem "filepicker-rails", "~> 1.0.0"
gem 'simple_form'

# authentication and authorization stacks
gem 'devise'
gem 'role_model'

# functionality stacks
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'watu_table_builder', :require => 'table_builder'

gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'faker'

group :development do
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'coveralls', require: false
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'rb-fchange', require: false
  gem 'rb-fsevent', require: false # For Guard file detection on Mac OS X
  gem 'rb-inotify', require: false
  gem 'rb-readline', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem "codeclimate-test-reporter", require: nil
  gem 'database_cleaner'

  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard' # OSX 10.8
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

and the application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module ApplicationNew
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
    config.time_zone = 'Singapore'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
    config.filepicker_rails.api_key = ENV["FILEPICKER_API_KEY"]

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true

    config.generators do |g|
      g.stylesheets false
      g.helper false
      g.javascripts false
      g.jbuilder false
      g.view_specs false
    end

    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**/}')]

  end
end
```

and production.rb

```
ApplicationNew::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Comment: That means that you've tried to run tests with *Factory_girl* with undefined, or not yet loaded factory `user`. Make sure that you've defined the factory, that the factory file has beebn added to repo index, and committed, and that tests are passed successfully. Only then ou shell commit it to heroku

Comment: I use it to create seed data locally, and it works fine

Comment: where are you store the factories?

Comment: under spec/factories, like the regular rspec directories

Comment: seems that heroku don't pick up the folders, type to specify them forcely

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not the best idea to use factory girl in a staging or production environment even just to seed the database. Typically you would include the gem in the test and development groups only so it wouldn't even be installed as part of your heroku deploy.

Great blog post on why this isn't a good idea:
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/factory_girl-for-seed-data